# grouping but ignore if blank

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to group (or at least make unique) a column `m_group_name` unless the group is empty. This is to basically see what doesn't yet have a group (and could then be edited to be placed into one) while being able to see the existing groups.

For example;

```
id  |  m_group_name
---------------------
 1  | Red
 2  | Blue
 3  | 
 4  | Red
 5  |
```

Which, ideally, would result in one red, one blue, and 2 blanks.

I've tried making the blanks NULL and giving it a UUID value (after adapting something similar found here on Stackoverflow), but it seems to make every NULL the same value.

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(m_group_name,UUID()) AS m_group FROM m GROUP BY m_group
```

Ideally I'd rather not use NULL to be perfectly honest

**EDIT:**
Realised that 'm_group_name' was incorrectly labelled as 'group' in the example - corrected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`SELECT * FROM m WHERE LENGTH(Group) IN (0, NULL)`
*`LENGTH(NULL)` will return `NULL`. `LENGTH('')` will return `0`.

am I right that you want to see ALL the rows that DON'T yet have a `Group`?

**EDIT**:
Okay, i read it carefully. How about this:

```
 SELECT * FROM m WHERE LENGTH(Group) NOT IN (0, NULL) GROUP BY Group
 UNION ALL
 SELECT * FROM m WHERE LENGTH(Group) IN (0, NULL)
```

Comment: All the rows that don't yet have a group along with the unique group names in one query - is it possible?

Comment: Thanks! That's got all of the blank groups, just need those other exisiting unique groups too, if it is possible :)

Comment: That would be the code below the "edit" section of my answer :-)

Comment: After a bit of playing around with the revised version, it works, but I had to remove NULL from the first set of IN brackets. For some reason including NULL resulted in nothing being outputted. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

That approach will not work because the UUID() function will return a single value per query, rather than a separate value for each row.

You can use the primary key:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(m_group_name,id) AS m_group FROM m GROUP BY m_group
```

Or you can use a different function, such as RAND(), to generate a separate value for each row. You can apply a hash function like MD5() to it if you want a string value:

```
SELECT *, IFNULL(m_group_name,md5(rand())) AS m_group FROM m GROUP BY m_group
```

Comment: That would explain why it appeared to use the same value - thanks for the explanation and the alternative answer :)